# How remove the decimals in tooltip pie chart Odoo 15?

Tags: javascript, odoo, chart.js, pie-chart, erp

[This tooltip is displayed when the mouse cursor hovers over a particular data point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Fy1.png)
[This is the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O6c0.png)
   `property_type_id = fields.Many2one("estate.property.type", string="Property Type")`
   `property_ids = fields.One2many("estate.property", "property_type_id", string="Properties")`
The number you are seeing in the image that appears in the tooltip with two zeros as if it were a float is the count of the properties.
How can I remove the decimals?
I found that odoo uses chart.js 2.9.3 but I don't know how to modify the JS to make the changes I want.
I tried to extend this code to remove the decimals somehow but I couldn't
I already saw all the links on the first 4 pages of Google, I watched tons of YouTube videos related to Odoo, Pie Charts, and Chart.js, I asked for help in WhatsApp and Telegram groups and nothing.

[this code(below) is in](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/widgets/pie_chart.js)

```
odoo.define('web.PieChart', function (require) {
"use strict";

/**
 * This widget render a Pie Chart. It is used in the dashboard view.
 */

var core = require('web.core');
var Domain = require('web.Domain');
var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var widgetRegistry = require('web.widget_registry');
const { loadLegacyViews } = require("@web/legacy/legacy_views");

var qweb = core.qweb;

var PieChart = Widget.extend({
    className: 'o_pie_chart',
    xmlDependencies: ['/web/static/src/legacy/xml/chart.xml'],

    /**
     * @override
     * @param {Widget} parent
     * @param {Object} record
     * @param {Object} node node from arch
     */
    init: function (parent, record, node) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);

        var modifiers = node.attrs.modifiers;
        var domain = record.domain.concat(
            Domain.prototype.stringToArray(modifiers.domain || '[]'));
        var arch = qweb.render('web.PieChart', {
            modifiers: modifiers,
            title: node.attrs.title || modifiers.title || modifiers.measure,
        });

        var pieChartContext = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(record.context));
        delete pieChartContext.graph_mode;
        delete pieChartContext.graph_measure;
        delete pieChartContext.graph_groupbys;

        this.subViewParams = {
            modelName: record.model,
            withButtons: false,
            withControlPanel: false,
            withSearchPanel: false,
            isEmbedded: true,
            useSampleModel: record.isSample,
            mode: 'pie',
        };
        this.subViewParams.searchQuery = {
            context: pieChartContext,
            domain: domain,
            groupBy: [],
            timeRanges: record.timeRanges || {},
        };

        this.viewInfo = {
            arch: arch,
            fields: record.fields,
            viewFields: record.fieldsInfo.dashboard,
        };
    },
    /**
     * Instantiates the pie chart view and starts the graph controller.
     *
     * @override
     */
    willStart: async function () {
        var self = this;
        const _super = this._super.bind(this, ...arguments);
        await loadLegacyViews({ rpc: this._rpc.bind(this) });
        var def1 = _super();

        var SubView = viewRegistry.get('graph');
        var subView = new SubView(this.viewInfo, this.subViewParams);
        var def2 = subView.getController(this).then(function (controller) {
            self.controller = controller;
            return self.controller.appendTo(document.createDocumentFragment());
        });
        return Promise.all([def1, def2]);
    },
    /**
     * @override
     */
    start: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.controller.$el);
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    /**
     * Call `on_attach_callback` for each subview
     *
     * @override
     */
    on_attach_callback: function () {
        this.controller.on_attach_callback();
    },
});

widgetRegistry.add('pie_chart', PieChart);

return PieChart;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the legacy graph renderer `_formatValue` function to use the new graph renderer `formatValue` function which will automatically remove the trailing zeros

***Example:***

```js
/* @odoo-module */

import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";

const GraphView = require('web.GraphView');
import { GraphRenderer } from "@web/views/graph/graph_renderer";
const viewRegistry = require("web.view_registry");
const LegacyGraphRenderer = viewRegistry.map.graph.prototype.config.Renderer;

patch(LegacyGraphRenderer.prototype, 'formatValue', {
    _formatValue(value, allIntegers = true) {
        return GraphRenderer.prototype.formatValue(value, allIntegers);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.
I try a lot but can´t make the code work.

this is the code in static/src/js/my_pie_chart.js

`console.log('hello world !');
/* @odoo-module */
//one part of your code goes here but i cut for the limit :(
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";
patch(LegacyGraphRenderer.prototype, 'formatValue', {
    _formatValue(value, allIntegers = true) {
        return GraphRenderer.prototype.formatValue(value, allIntegers);
    }
});
`
the screen turn white when run the code and this errors appear: (next comment below)

Comment: this is the error in the console thanks you again for take your time and answer me https://imgtr.ee/image/IdBZVg

This is the file my_pie_chart.js
https://imgtr.ee/image/IdB4HK

Comment: You forgot to add `/* @odoo-module */` at the top of the js file

Comment: @SomeDay Odoo will look at the first line of a JS file and check if it contains the string `@odoo-module`. If so, it will automatically be converted to an Odoo module. You can't use `import` because you forgot to add `@odoo-module`.

Comment: you're the best.
Thank you so much, It works perfect! 
right now I'm learning JavaScript and OWL to know how to do this kind of thing.
Now the administrators can close this post.